# Linux kernel: packet is forwarded to another interface, but isn't sent onwards

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming

I've made a `virtual network interface` that forwards any `packet` it receives to a physical interface `eth2`, with the intention of sending it to whichever destination is required.

The virtual interface's `hard_start_xmit` function receives the packet, changes the source`MAC and IP`, sets the handling device to be the physical interface, and sets the packet type to `PACKET_OUTGOING`.

```
static int forward_packet(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev) {
    char switched_device_name[] = "eth2";
    struct net_device *switched_device = dev_get_by_name(switched_device_name);
    int ifrx_output;
    u32 switched_device_ip;

    if (!switched_device) {
        printk("Error: Couldn't get device %s for switching.\n", switched_device_name);
        return -1;
    }

    skb->dev = switched_device;
    skb->input_dev = switched_device;
    skb->pkt_type = PACKET_OUTGOING;

    switched_device_ip = get_interface_ip(switched_device);
    change_source_mac_and_ip(skb, switched_device->dev_addr, switched_device_ip);

    ifrx_output = netif_rx(skb);
    printk("netif_rx returned %d.\n", ifrx_output);
    return 0;
}
```

I tested this code, and while the packet does appear in the physical interface's `tcpdump`, there's no trace of it in the destination machine.

The only reason I can think something like this would happen is because the physical interface treats it as an incoming packet with no need to pass it on. However as far as I can tell, only `skb->pkt_type` determines that.

What other packet changes could I be missing?

Comment: Does change_source_mac_and_ip properly update the IP header checksum of the packet? Otherwise it might get dropped if it is checked on some place

Comment: @Ctx Yes, I've compared the forwarded packet after alterations against a packet created directly for the physical interface, and they're the same.

Comment: Have you tried just calling `hard_start_xmit(skb, switched_device)`? I would guess that Linux by default prohibits incoming packets from going back out the same interface as a sanity check.